# Fuzzy String Matching

Tags: string, algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

I have a requirement within my application to fuzzy match a string value inputted by the user, against a datastore.

I am basically attempting to find possible duplicates in the process in which data is added to the system.

I have looked at Metaphone, Double Metaphone, and SoundEx, and the conclusion I have came to is they are all well and good when dealing with a single word input string; however I am trying to match against a undefined number of words (they are actually place names).

I did consider actually splitting each of the words from the string (removing any I define as noise words), then implementing some logic which would determine which place names within my data store, best matched (based on the keys from the algorithm I choose); the advantage I see in this, would be I could selectively tighten up, or loosen the match criteria to suit the application: however this does seem a little dirty to me.

So my question(s) are:

1: Am I approaching this problem in the right way, yes I understand it will be quite expensive; however (without going to deeply into the implementation) this information will be coming from a memcache database.

2: Are there any algorithms out there, that already specialise in phonetically matching multiple words? If so, could you please provide me with some information on them, and if possible their strengths and limitations.

Comment: it is not very clear what you are actually trying to do. what is the input? what is the expected output?

Comment: If you don't want to go the route of tokenizing the names into words, character bigrams and trigrams would be worth looking into. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Comment: You could try the Levensthein distance, which returns a number for the differences between two strings. Whether it is useful for finding the proper spelling for a "phonetic" one (can you give an example of this?) can be easily tested. Most examples are for single words, but it can work with longer strings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into a [Locality-sensitive Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) such as the [Nilsimsa Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilsimsa_Hash). I have used Nilsimsa to "hash" craigslists posts across various cities to search for duplicates (NOTE: I'm not a CL employee, just a personal project I was working on).

Most of these methods aren't as tunable as you may want (basically you can get some loosely-defined "edit distance" metric) and they're not phonetic, solely character based.